# I was installing mongodb and want to create a symbolic link in my ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, symlink

This is the path.

> /home/neeraj/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

And this is the command

> sudo ln -s ~/Downloads/mongodb-linux-x86_64-amazon-3.2.1/bin/mongod /usr/local/sbin/mongod

But then it says this:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/local/sbin/mongod’: File exists

And when I try to run this command

> mongod --version

It says:

> mongod: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like a shared library for ssl is missing or cannot be found at the expected location by the mongod binary. Try reinstalling mongod which should fix the library dependency.

Comment: @JakobRunge I guess I was being stupid

Comment: Nice to hear you could solve it!